# Is Revelation 6:8 an allusion to Ezekiel 14:21-23?

Tags: revelation, ezekiel, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible, messiah

> [Eze 14:21-23 HNV] (21) For thus says the Lord GOD: How much more when I send **my four sore judgments on Yerushalayim, the sword, and the famine, and the evil animals, and the pestilence**, to **cut off from it man and animal!** (22) Yet, behold, **therein shall be left a remnant** that shall be **carried forth**, both sons and daughters: behold, they shall come forth to you, and you shall see their way and their doings; and you shall be comforted concerning the evil that I have brought on Yerushalayim, even concerning all that I have brought on it. (23) They shall comfort you, when you see their way and their doings; and you shall know that I have not done without cause all that I have done in it, says the Lord GOD.
>
> [Rev 6:8 ASV] (8) And I saw, and behold, a pale horse: and he that sat upon him, his name was Death; and Hades followed with him. And there was given unto them authority over the fourth part of the earth [IE: Jerusalem], **to kill with sword, and with famine, and with death, and by the wild beasts** of the earth [IE: Israel].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The judgment prophesied against Judea and Jerusalem in Revelation parallels much of Ezekiel's prophesy against Israel and Judah.  The four judgments of Ezekiel are pictured again by the four horsemen in Rev. 6:2-8.  The famine is pronounced in Ezek. 4:16-17, and again in 5:12 and 6:12, and chap. 24.

The sword of Ezek. 14:21 is also referred to as the slaughter in Ezek. 9:5-10, and ch. 21. It also brings in the 1/3 destruction in Ezek. 5:12 which crosses to the 1/3 destruction in Rev. 8:6-12.

As the focus of both Ezekiel and Revelation was the siege of Jerusalem, the destruction of Jerusalem, and of the temple there are a lot of parallels between the two books.

I list several more parallels at my post "Ezekiel in Revelation - Part I..." at my site [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2019/07/13/ezekiel-in-revelation-part-i-overview-comparison/).

Comment: Excellent resource, thanks. Talking about resources, are you familiar with the Preterist forum?:  https://revelationrevolution.org/forums/forum/forum/

Comment: @Ruminator - I have visited that site before, but it's been a while.  Last time they were new at their research, and I thought they needed to continue to mature.  My research focuses at preteristcentral.com; preteristarchive.com (great site); and MrDonpreston.com.  There are several others.  As always tho, verify everything against the scriptures b/c no one has everything correct.

Answer (score 0):

While not exact or in the same sequence, the four killings are similarly described in Ezekiel:

> This is what the Lord says: But even if I even send out my four grievous punishments sword, and famine, and harmful animals, and death upon Ierousalem so as to utterly destroy human and cattle from it; ([Ezekiel 14:21 LXX](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/nets/edition/38-iezekiel-nets.pdf))
>
> τάδε λέγει κύριος ἐὰν δὲ καὶ τὰς τέσσαρας ἐκδικήσεις μου τὰς **πονηράς ῥομφαίαν** καὶ **λιμὸν** καὶ **θηρία πονηρὰ** καὶ **θάνατον** ἐξαποστείλω ἐπὶ Ιερουσαλημ τοῦ ἐξολεθρεῦσαι ἐξ αὐτῆς ἄνθρωπον καὶ κτῆνος
>
> And I looked, and behold, a pale horse! And its rider's name was Death, and Hades followed him. And they were given authority over a fourth of the earth, to kill with **sword** and with **famine** and with **pestilence** and by **wild beasts** of the earth. (Revelation 6:8 ESV)
>
> καὶ εἶδον καὶ ἰδοὺ ἵππος χλωρός καὶ ὁ καθήμενος ἐπάνω αὐτοῦ ὄνομα αὐτῷ ὁ θάνατος καὶ ὁ ᾅδης ἠκολούθει μετ᾽ αὐτοῦ καὶ ἐδόθη αὐτοῖς ἐξουσία ἐπὶ τὸ τέταρτον τῆς γῆς ἀποκτεῖναι ἐν **ῥομφαίᾳ** καὶ ἐν **λιμῷ** καὶ ἐν **θανάτῳ** καὶ ὑπὸ τῶν **θηρίων** τῆς γῆς

However, there is nothing to suggest the writer of Revelation sees these on a limited scale applying only to Jerusalem and Israel:

> And I saw, and behold, a pale horse: and he that sat upon him, his name was Death; and Hades followed with him. And there was given unto them authority over **the fourth part of the earth [IE: Jerusalem]**, to kill with sword, and with famine, and with death, and by the wild beasts **of the earth [IE: Israel]**.

Nowhere is there support to limit "a fourth of the earth" to Jerusalem or to understand "the wild beasts of the earth" as limited to, or from, Israel.

If the writer of Revelation had Ezekiel in view, he was also purposeful to alter it:

> Ezekiel: ferocious broad-sword, famine, ferocious wild beasts, pestilence
> Revelation: broad-sword, famine, pestilence, wild beasts

In addition to changing the sequence, neither the broad-sword nor the wild beasts have the additional description of "ferocious" (πονηράς). Thus, the allusion, if there is one, is also meant to be seen as distinct from Ezekiel. That is to say, the same general methods used to about judgment on Jerusalem in Ezekiel are used to bring judgment to a fourth of the entire earth in Revelation.

Comment: You r thinking in English.  The "earth" - eretz - was the land & the ppl of the land the prophet was sent to warn.  So as in Isa. 13, the earth that moved out of its place was Babylon & the ends of the heavens was the borders of the king's dominion.  In Rev. the prophet is Christ, & Christ was sent to the lost sheep of the house of Israel - the remnant of Judea.  The "earth" of that prophesy was Judea & Jerusalem.  The "heaven" of that prophesy concerned the king's dominion, or the ruler's dominion - the Roman empire.  The rainbow around the throne scene was the promise of limited judgment.

Comment: @Gina 1. Revelation is the revelation of Jesus Christ. Nowhere does He call Himself a prophet - His self-descriptions are not as a prophet. 2. The Revelation was given to the seven churches in Asia, not the lost sheep of the house of Israel. 3. "eretz" is Hebrew. The revelation was given in Greek and there is nothing in the text or context to support the idea that 6:8 is speaking about a judgment limited to Israel or Jerusalem. 4. The message of Revelation is one of global judgement and recreation (a new heaven and a new earth) not a limited judgment and limited restoration (Jerusalem/Israel).

Comment: Revelation was written to the 1st century believers, and Christ told them He was coming "soon", and that things in the book were all "shortly" to come.  He called Himself a prophet in the gospels (Matt. 10:41; 13:57, etc.)  He was one of the 2 messengers, another name for a prophet, one who carries the word of another that is mentioned in Mal. 3:1, & the prophet like unto Moses (Deu. 18:15-20).  Of course He was a prophet to Judea & Jerusalem.  Revelation is our record that Christ completely fulfilled the laws of the temple, & that the temple was to be destroyed.  That the temple was ....

Comment: ...destroyed is the secular proof of that prophesy.  Revelation is our example of how God will and does continue to judge the nations that rebel against Him.  Christ has been reigning over all the earth ever since AD 70.  He would not have lied to those 1st century believers telling them He was coming soon, & still make everyone wait 2,000 years later for HIs coming.  That is the wrong perspective.  It creates doubt, confusion, and disbelief.  If He said He was coming soon, but He didn't  - then why should ppl believe Him?  Take Him at His word.

Comment: New heaven and new earth is the metaphor of the covenant = the new covenant.  It originates in Isa. 65 &  66 speaking of the renewal of the covenant with the remnant of Israel (Judah & Benjamin) coming back out of the Babylonian captivity.  Did God recreate the physical heavens & earth in 539 BC?  Hebraic idiom for the covenant, & for the temple.  It is not literally speaking of a new physical cosmos.

Comment: @Gina Interesting. So the text is to be understood literally except when it must be read symbolically or as a Hebraic idiom (which the 1st century believers are supposed to discern and understand from the Greek text). Also if Hebraic idioms are relevant, why aren't passages such as Deut 7:4, 11:17, 28:20, and Joshua 23:16 applicable? All speak about utter destruction quickly (ἐν τάχει) when the Israelites worshiped other gods and that never happened "quickly." Why must the first century believers understand "quickly" differently then God applied it to the first Israelites in the Promised Land?

Comment: Also I think the idea that Jesus as a prophet as in the Gospel must take precedence over His self descriptions to the churches in the letter is far-fetched. I doubt any of the seven churches would have understood their messages in that manner.

Comment: Prophesy uses metaphors and symbols.  The statement that He was returning "soon" is clear.  How does the word "soon" symbolize 2,000 years?  Acts 3:22 & John 6:14 both show that the ppl recognized Christ as the prophet they were looking for.  See also "Was Jesus A Prophet?"  at https://www.blueletterbible.org/faq/don_stewart/don_stewart_1335.cfm   And, as space is limited here, if you would just go to my blog you could get many of these questions answered from my posts - ShreddingTheVeil.org.  The time texts of the NT are very clearly stated.